# Solving recurrences where the master theorem does not apply (I.e. a isn’t constant)

Tags: recursion, recurrence

I need to solve the following recurrence:

T(n) = 2^n T(n/3) + n^2

I've tried expanding it out to find a pattern, but it looks like everything just keeps getting messier and messier. Is there a better way to approach recurrence relations with a non-constant amount of sub-problems?